# Holy Glitch, Batman!

Tags: support, chat, rss

The Morningstar RSS feed post form Wizard's RSS feed is back with a vengeance. The feed post will show up in the chat RSS feed hourly if not more often. What can we do to address the issue?

Answer (score 6):

I think I see what you mean - the [Morningstar](http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/news/morningstar) post is reappearing over and over in our chat's RSS ticker, right? It seems that in [their RSS feed](http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Globals/Services/ArticleFeed.aspx), the Morningstar post is getting its *pubDate* property updated *reguarly* to be *today.* Heck, we're all aware it was published a couple of weeks ago, but check what it's set to at the time of this writing:

```
<dc:creator/>
<title>Morningstar</title>
<link>http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/news/morningstar</link>
<description/>
<pubDate>Tue, 08 Jul 2014 00:00:04 PST</pubDate>
<guid>http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/news/morningstar#93104</guid>
```

And tomorrow, it'll say it was published tomorrow.

Let's remove their feed from the chat temporarily.

We can take another look at it in a few days, and if it's not screwing up any more at that point, we'll add their feed back to chat.

Comment: As it was writ, so it now is.

Comment: Mind elaborating? That sounds like a separate bug altogether.

Comment: When the question was asked, we did a few tests, and checked the RSS page when it reposted. The RSS page was identical, with the timestamp and guid etc, but I see perhaps our browsers were just cached.  I have this same feed on my blog and it does not repost the morningstar entry.